# rails options_from_collection_for_select ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have 2 model:1. category. 2. product. Each categori has many products and each product just in one category.

1. Category.rb

   `class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
   end`
2. Product.rb

`class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end`

I have 2 `options_from_collection_for_select` in my project that one of them show categories and other show product

```
<select name="task[category_id]">
   <%= options_from_collection_for_select(@list_of_category,:id, :name,@task.category_id) %>
</select>

<select name="task[product_id]">
   <%= options_from_collection_for_select(@list_of_product,:id, :name,@task.product_id) %>
</select>
```

Now I want set `onchange` that when I select a category from first `select`, the other one just show product's that exists in the category that selected. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onchangehandler` on select box , like

```
<%= options_from_collection_for_select(@list_of_category,:id, :name,@task.category_id,:onchange => 'yourfunction()') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax call to repopulate data. Something like

"abc" %>

<%= options_from_collection_for_select(@list_of_category,:id, :name,@task.category_id), :id => "def" %>`enter code here`

$("#abc").change(function(){
#yuour code ...`enter code here`
});